# Include child elements on click event listener on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, dom

https://jsfiddle.net/y444stqv/3/

How do I include all the child elements within the parent "click" event listener? For example, I dynamically create the following html:

```
  <div id="content">
     <div id="donotexecuteclicklistener">But don't include me!</div>
      <!-- Dynamically generated -->
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item item-0">
          <h3>Item 0</h3>
          <p>Some desc</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-1">
          <h3>Item 1</h3>
          <p>Some desc</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-2">
          <h3>Item 2</h3>
          <p>Some desc</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-3">
          <h3>Item 3</h3>
          <p>Some desc</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to bind a click handler to each "item" div. So, if you click any element that is a child of the "item" (i.e. the child "h3" or "p" tags) node, I still want to execute the "handleClick" click handler. BUT, when you click on the id "donotexecuteclicklistener", I don't want that click handler to trigger.

```
  var items = [];
  var $content = document.getElementById('content');

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     // using ES6 template literals for ease
     var item = `
        <div class="item" id="item-${i}">
            <h3>Item ${i}</h3>
            <p>Some desc about item ${i}</p>
        </div>
     `;

     items.push(item);
  }

  var html = items.join(' ');
  $content.innerHTML = html;

  var handleClick = function(event) {
      console.log('do something with item', this, event);
  }

  $content.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.id);
      var elements = $content.querySelectorAll('.item');
      var hasMatch = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(elements, event.target) >= 0;
      console.log(hasMatch);

      if (hasMatch) {
        handleClick.call(event.target, event);
      }
  })
```

Comment: "*I want to use event delegation to bind a click handler…*" you are misusing  the expression "*event delegation*", which is about capturing bubbling events, not attaching listeners. Please post runnable code here, not elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use concept of event delegation to its fullest potential, attach a single listener to the *content* element, then see where events come from to determine the response.

If it comes from an element inside a div with class *item*, do whatever, e.g.

```js
function handleClick(e){
  var el = e.target;
  var div = getParentByClass(el, 'item');
  if (div) {
    console.log(div.className);
  } else {
    console.log('no item parent')
   }
}

// Get self or first parent with particular class
// May be replaced by Element.closest in future
function getParentByClass(el, className) {
  do {
    if (el.classList.contains(className)) {
      return el;
    } else {
      el = el.parentNode;
    }
  } while (el && el.parentNode)
}


window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
}
//*/
```

```html
<div id="content">
     <div id="donotexecuteclicklistener">But don't include me!</div>
      <!-- Dynamically generated -->
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item item-0">
          <h3>Item 0</h3>
          <p>Some desc</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-1">
          <h3>Item 1</h3>
          <p>Some desc</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-2">
          <h3>Item 2</h3>
          <p>Some desc</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-3">
          <h3>Item 3</h3>
          <p>Some desc</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Also see [*Element.closest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest). You might also consider a more generic "get parent by selector", but performance might be slower, e.g.

```
function getParentBySelector(el, selector) {
  var node;
  var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  els = els && els.length? Array.from(els) : [];

  while (el && el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    node = els.find(x => x === el);
    if (node) return node;
  }   
}
```

And call it by:

```
var div = getParentBySelector(el, 'div.item');
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens by default! When an element is triggered on a child, it is "bubbled up" to the parent elements. You can see that the `click` event is bubbled with the `Event.bubbles` property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles).

The fact that the element was dynamically generated does not affect this behavior: the events will still bubble on dynamically generated elements.

In order to get the element the event happened to, you can use `e.target`.

```
ancestor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const element = e.target;
});
```

Be careful: the `e.stopPropagation()` method cancels this bubbling functionality, so you need to make sure you aren't calling it anywhere. If you're having trouble getting the events to bubble, this may be the culprit.